# I am having an issue connecting to a device via port forward from another network

Tags: networking, router, routing

I am having some type of routing problem where I cannot
connect to a Raspberry pi via a port forward behind a Wi-Fi 
router. I have a network set up consisting of a Comcast Wi-Fi 
router (connected to the Internet). To extend my Wi-Fi range, 
I have two additional routers, both connected to the Comcast 
router via Ethernet. My network layout is below (excuse the 
simple ASCII art).

- My laptop is connected via Wi-Fi to Router1 on its LAN side.
- The RPi is connected via Ethernet to Router2 on its LAN side.

  - The RPi's SSH port (22) is port-forwarded from Router2 as port 3333
    (so for example, from the laptop I use `ssh pi@1.1.1.20 -p 3333`)

```
 ------------
  \  Laptop  \ -  -  -  -  -
   \ 2.2.2.100\         
    \__________\_          |
    [____________]   
                           |

    \        /          \        /         \        /
  +----------------+  +----------------+   +----------------+
  |  Comcast       |  |  Router1       |   |  Router2       |
  |  Wi-Fi AP      |  |  Wi-Fi AP      |   |  Wi-Fi AP      |
  | LAN:1.1.1.1/24 |  | LAN:2.2.2.1/24 |   | LAN:3.3.3.1/24 |
  |                |  | WAN:1.1.1.10   |   | WAN:1.1.1.20   |
  +----------------+  +----------------+   +----------------+
      |   |                 |                  |  |
      |   +-----------------+------------------+  |
      |                                           |
      |                                           |
    Internet                                 +-----------+
                                             |  Rasp Pi  |
                                             | 3.3.3.100 |
                                             +-----------+
```

This is where I have the problem. SSH to the RPi using the 
forwarded port does not seem to work from my laptop behind 
Router1. If I move my laptop to connect directly to the 
Comcast Router (where it has an IP address from the Comcast 
router of 1.1.1.100), then everything works great.

Does Comcast simply not allow the connection due to it being 
behind a router? I don't have any firewall rules set up that 
block any of this traffic—I can only assume it's a routing 
issue at the Comcast AP.

Comment: Is router 1 set to allow all outbound traffic? I know it should be, by default, but maybe you have that turned off(?). With laptop behind R1, can you ping 3.3.3.1?

Comment: I've disabled the firewall on Router1 to simplify fixing this issue. From the Laptop, I can ping 1.1.1.1 and another client on the Comcast subnet, 1.1.1.101. I cannot seem to ping Router2 (it's WAN side 1.1.1.20). However, if I ping Router 2 (1.1.1.20) from the machine at 1.1.1.101 (not shown on diagram), it does ping.

Comment: Can you hardwire the laptop to Router 1 LAN? that would rule out wireless. Aside from that it seems that 1.1.1.10 cant reach 1.1.1.20. So you are correct, it may be the Comcast AP,can you get into it with the default login/PW and look around? I have worked a lot of their equipment and that just doesn't sound like something they would bother with. One last thought, do you know if anything is actually getting *through* router 1?   Can 2.2.2.100 ping *anyone* on the 1.1.1.x network?

Comment: @Larryc, your comment about pinging anyone in 1.1.1.x reminded me to check pinging from both directions. There is a machine on the Comcast AP (1.1.1.101) that a device from behind both Router1 and Router2 *can* ping. However, If you are behind Router1, you cannot ping Router2. Also, if you are behind Router2, you similarly cannot ping Router 1. Since both  being behind Router1 and Router2 still allows you to ping 1.1.1.101, it seems like the Comcast AP is somehow preventing routing to/from those next routers--I just don't know how. The Comcast router does not provide as much control :)

Comment: I ran a SYN traceroute from the Pi (3.3.3.100) to Router1 (traceroute -nT 1.1.1.10) a couple of time and the last one worked. *Now* I can ping and connect to the port forwards. All I can say is WTF? I wonder if the ARP tables were bad at the Comcast AP and this shook them into place? At any rate, I appreciate the help @Larryc